# How to extend Quickbooks API entity with more fields

Tags: php, web-services, api, extension-methods, quickbooks-online

I'm needing to extend the the employee entity by adding more rows of data to it. For example one row I need to add I might call 'types', so that I can know what type of employee someone is (e.g. administrator, journeyman, owner etc).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks doesn't allow you to just add "rows", or add fields to the "rows".

There are custom fields you can use to store additional data as you're describing. Docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting/0040_create_custom_fields

Comment: Been some time. Sorry it took so long to mark this answer as correct. Lol. I just posted my second ever question and was fumbling through my profile when I came across this question again. Thanks for answering. At the time, this did help me to realize that I wasn't going to be able to achieve what I wanted to do, due to the limitations set by the QB software. Thanks again!